# Poll method for custom panel

Tags: python, scripting, interface, panel

How do I setup the poll method for a panel causing it to only display when 2 objects are selected ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return len(context.selected_objects) == 2
```