# Toggle an operator

Tags: python, add-on, operator

How do you toggle an operator? A prop works

```
row.prop(bpy.context.object, 'lock_rotation', text = "", icon = "UNLOCKED", toggle = True)
```

but using an operator does not:

```
row.operator('object.idname', text = "", icon = "EVENT_O", toggle = True)
```

I get this error when "toggle = True" is added to an Operator:

```
TypeError: UILayout.operator(): was called with invalid keyword argument(s) (toggle), expected (operator, text, text_ctxt, translate, icon, emboss, depress, icon_value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In this case it's a layout display option.**

The `toggle` option for

> **[`UILayout.prop`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.prop)**
>
> **toggle** (int in [-1, 1], (optional)) – Use toggle widget for boolean values, or a checkbox when disabled (the default is -1 which
> uses toggle only when an icon is displayed)

```
layout.prop(context.object, "some_bool_prop", toggle=True)
```

is to make the boolean property appear like a button in the UI, rather than a checkbox. Please note that `context` is always passed to a draw method, so there is never a need to see `bpy.context`

To do the same with an operator, there is the `bpy.ops.wm.context_toggle()` operator, (Seen often in the keymaps)

```
op = layout.operator("wm.context_toggle")
op.data_path = "object.some_bool_prop"
```

where the data path is relative to context.

An operator is displayed as an embossed button by default in the UI, setting

```
op = layout.operator("wm.context_toggle", emboss=False)
```

will make it more link like.

**BoolVectorProperty**

The `lock_rotation` is a vector property with a boolean for each axis.

[image]

Example setting only the X axis (index = 0) lock. *New draw method for `Text Editor > Templates > Pythons > UI Panel Simple`  The panel only polls if there is a context object. This ensures that the object is the one that has the properties being displayed.  Not doing so will result in an error, generally notable by seeing 'None`or`NoneType` in the error message*

[Hide Panel With Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182586/hide-panel-with-python)

```
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(obj, "lock_rotation", index=0, toggle=False)
        row.prop(obj, "lock_rotation", index=0, toggle=True)

        op = row.operator("wm.context_toggle")
        op.data_path = "object.lock_rotation[0]"
        op = row.operator("wm.context_toggle", emboss=False)
        op.data_path = "object.lock_rotation[0]"
```

Comment: Thanks! The reason I was trying to use an Operator (row.operator) rather than Prop is because I was trying to setup an Execute function in the Operator to offer more control, and because `row.prop(obj, "lock_rotation", index=0, toggle=True)` throws a `...'None" assignment AnyType type` error when an object is deleted in the scene. I seem to be stuck between either having the error but with a working toggle, or getting rid of the error but not having toggle functionality. Still trying to wrap my head around it

Comment: Sounds to me like you have a poll issue... recently answered https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/212075/how-to-enable-or-disable-panels-with-the-click-of-a-button  Make sure your panel doesn't poll when `context.object is None` other wise `None.lock_rotation` is going to give errors, when ... say ... you remove...

Comment: Genius! That did it, thanks