# how to get autocomplete for layout in the console?

Tags: python

I am trying out this example from the templates:

```
class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "output"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
```

but now i'm stuck with getting autocompletion for layout.

Normally you can type in the commands e.g. "bpy." and with tab you will see all commands which are possible.

Since i now don't have "self" how can i get the autocompletion for layout?

Comment: AFAIK no simple way to do this.  Instead can `print(dir(self.layout))` in a draw method, or consult the docs for `bpy.types.UILayout`  Somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/182852/15543

Comment: I use this tool within PyCharm for writing scripts so i can get Intellisense, auto complete etc.  https://github.com/Korchy/blender_autocomplete